# How to click on element with specific width puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm having a problem clicking on an element, my script tries to click on this element before the label and add to cart button are visible, and I don't know why this happens since I passed the `visible:true` parameter I believe  I think this shouldn't happen, however, to fix this problem I thought of clicking on the element when it had a specific width, but I don't know how to do it, look at my script below:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');         
const fs = require('fs').promises;                                                                                                              

(async () => {                                    
 try{                                              
  console.log("Started!")                        
  const browser = await 
  puppeteer.launch({         
   executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium',            
   //headless:false,                               
   args:['--no-sandbox', '--disable-gpu']        
  });                                             
  const page = await browser.newPage();   
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);        
  const blockedResourceTypes = ["image", "bacon", "imageset", "stylesheet", "font", "texttrack", "csp_report", "media", "object", "sub_frame", "main_frame"]
  const allowURLs = [/*Index.css*/"https://images.lojanike.com.br/site/ni/dist/css/Index.css?v=5b95e1dc7eff61bf78f523058eb924e6",                                   ]
  const allowedRequest = req => !blockedResourceTypes.includes(req.resourceType()) || allowURLs.includes(req.url())                               
  page.on('request', (req) => {
   if (allowedRequest(req)) {                       
    req.continue();
   }
   else {
    req.abort();
   }                                             
  });                                             
  const cookiesString = await fs.readFile('./cookies.json');
  const cookies = JSON.parse(cookiesString);
  await.page.setCookie(...cookies);
  await page.goto('https://www.nike.com.br/air-max-1-x-clot-infantil-24-33-67-80-445-308385', { waitUntil:'domcontentloaded', timeout:0});
  const tamanho = await page.$x('//label[@for="tamanho__id32"]', {visible:true})                  
  await tamanho[0].click('//label[@for="tamanho__id32"]');                                        
  await page.waitForSelector('button#btn-comprar')                                   
  page.click('button#btn-comprar')                
  console.log("Added to car!")         
 }                                                
 catch(err){
  console.log("Erro, elemento não está contido na pagina ou erro inesperado!", err)}     
})();
```

How can I click on the label for example when it has a width of 32px?  I tried it that way and it didn't work:

```
tamanho = await page.$x('//label[@for="tamanho__id32"]', {visible:true, width:60})
```

How can I click on an element that has a specific width?

**Detail:**

**If** I put `load` instead of `domcontentloaded` it works, the problem is that load delays my script as it will have to wait for the page to load, so I need to click on an element that has a specific width, something like  the code I tried, and it works lol

Comment: #1 an screenshot of your form would be helpful because this is somewhat confusing **"before the label and add to cart button are visible"** #2 with selenium you would not have problems

Comment: it seems like you can just set an interval to wait until there is a button with that specific width

Answer (score 2):

You can set an interval to check a certain condition:

```
const label = document.querySelector('label[for="tamanho__id32"]');

const _interval = setInterval(() => {
    const width = label.offsetWidth;

    if (width === 32) {
        label.click();
        clearInterval(_interval);
    }
}, 200);

// clear interval after some time                    
setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(_interval);
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive function:

```
async function search(page) {
  try {
    const tamanho = await page.$("label[for='tamanho__id32']");
    const box = await tamanho.boundingBox();

    if (box.width == 32) {
      await tamanho.click();
    } else {
      throw new Error();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    await page.waitForTimeout(1000);

    return search();
  }
}
```

It will check every second whether the selector and the proper width is there. It uses the [boundingBox](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#elementhandleboundingbox) method to get the elements width. Just define it outside your code and await it instead of your XPath-Selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [page.waitForSelector(selector[, options])](https://www.tools4testing.com/contents/puppeteer/puppeteer-waitforselector) - and attach the listener to your `.launch()` promise

```
puppeteer.launch({         
   executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium',            
   //headless:false,                               
   args:['--no-sandbox', '--disable-gpu']        
  }).then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page
    .waitForSelector('label[for="tamanho__id32"]')
    .then(() => {
        page.goto('https://www.nike.com.br/air-max-1-x-clot-infantil-24-33-67-80-445-308385');
     }
    browser.close();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

function to wait for the button to be a specific width before taking an action:

```
function waitForCondition(obj, len, callBack){    
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    if(obj.width() >= len){
      callBack();
    }else{
      waitForCondition(obj, len, callBack);
    }
  },250);
}

   var obj=$("#myButton");
     waitForCondition( obj , 80, function(){
        alert("threshold met");
   });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shawnsBrain66/mt8kd0jb/16/)

Comment: Error `ReferenceError: window is not defined`

Comment: did you look at the jsfiddle? It does work

Comment: In this case I'm using node js and that's why it doesn't work

Comment: @Gjsks in node setTimeout is global. I would suggest setInterval and clearInterval that are better related to your needs.